# Return value from Bootstrap model to the element which is clicked to open modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I created a Bootstrap modal. It will open when i click the text element. Here is the code:

```
<input type="text" id="btnModel" >

$( "#btnModel" ).click(function() {
     $('#myModal').modal('show')
  });
```

When I click a button in the model, it should set the value of input text element `btnModel` (which is used to open modal). How can modal access the element which was used to open the modal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a class `pressedModal` on the element pressed in order to open the modal.

Access that element with this class from modal, and then remove this class on modal close:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnModel', function() {
    $(this).addClass('pressedModal'); 
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  });
```

In modal window:

```
$(document).on('click', '#button_in_modal', function() {
    var buttonPressed = $('.pressedModal');
    // do your stuff
});

$(document).on('click', '#close_modal', function() {
    var buttonPressed = $('.pressedModal');
    buttonPressed.removeClass('pressedModal');
});
```